# Cannot find data saved with SQLite or openFileOutput(), folder is shown empty

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying create data within one app and later use it in another app. My problem is that I cannot find the files created in the first app, although I am sure they excist, because I am able to read them in the first app. The path where the data is saved should be `data/user/0/com...`. When I open the folder `0` in the File Explorer of Android it is shown empty.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: paste the code that you are using

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: If you are using the default location,(which appears to be the case) then the App's data, including the database is only accessible by the App. The solution is to access the data via a content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Other apps do not have access to this, except on rooted devices (and only then if the app is designed to use root to browse the whole device). If you are testing a `debug` build, the Device File Explorer in Android Studio can show you your file.

Comment: Oh that's right I can now access the files from the Device File Explorer, but is there a way to export a file somewhere so you can move it to your computer?

Comment: @Argos: In the Device File Explorer, right-click over the file and choose "Save As".

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am searching for a way to do this programmatically

Comment: @Argos: Your app has read-write access to its own files. You can use Java I/O to copy those files to some other location, such as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Or, save the files to external storage in the first place.